# Как показать View поверх угла CardView?

Tags: android, cardview

Всем привет, нужно поверх `CardView` показать `ImageView` в углу. Карточки реализованы в `SwipeStack` через `RecyclerView` адаптер. Не получается даже показать её поверх карточки

```
<FrameLayout>
    <CardView/>
    <ImageView/>
<FrameLayout/>
```

Картинка показывается **за** карточкой, а не поверх её.

Как показать ее **поверх** карточки в углу?

Comment: Такие штуки реализуются через `ItemDecorator`

Comment: @Alex Kisel, в SwipeStack нет их поддержки

Comment: elevation задайте. у cardview он по умолчанию выше нуля. и скорее всего картинка просто под кард вьюхой

Comment: elevation > 1dp для ImageView решит вашу проблему